# How can I remove specific element from a list?

Tags: clojure

I know this might be a silly question, but I don't get it.
I have some data:

```
(def x (range 1 14))

-> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13)
```

I want to return a list without "3" for example.
Googling "clojure remove item from list" took me to this:

```
  (remove pred coll)
```

So I tried to use example with `even?`:

```
  (remove even? x) 

  -> (1 3 5 7 9 11 13)
```

Great! It works with my data! I just need to change `pred`. And my first guess would be:

```
  (remove (= 3) x)

  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

Ok, we don't need to evaluate `(= 3)`, so let's put `#` before:

```
  (remove #(= 3) x)

  clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (1)` passed to...
```

I know it is trivial, but still how can I do it?

Comment: Clojure allows varying number of arguments (and is not typed) so when you write `(= 3)` or `#(= 3)` nor the compiler or runtime can't know: 1/ how many args are missing, 2/ where to put them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use:

```
(remove #(= 3 %) x)
```

`#(= 3)` does not take a parameter (but `remove` tries to pass one to that function).

`#(= 3 %)` takes one parameter, and calls `=` with that parameter (`%`) and `3`.

Answer (score 17):

I like using sets for this kind of thing. So clean..

Remove elements:

`(remove #{3 5} [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])`

Keep elements:

`(keep #{7 5 3} [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])`

Check if element exists:

`(some #{5} [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9])`

This works because when a set is used as a function of one argument, it returns the argument if it was inside of the set. In the remove example, the elements `3` and `5` cause the set to return a *truthy* value: themselves. The same thing happens for both the `keep` and `some` examples, except that the `some` example has the added benefit of returning the first element in your collection that's also in the set.

Comment: This is quite helpful as well! I will keep this in mind.